# Background color in Chrome vs. Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to get an inset effect on buttons through CSS. In Firefox this looks like in the first image, in Chrome like the second. I do not understand why and how to resolve this. Can anybody please give me a hint on what's going on? Thanks.

**Firefox**

[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

Here's the markup:

```
<div id="controls">
  <div class="musicStyles"><span class="btnLetter">S</span>
    <input type="checkbox" class="box"data-value="Classic" data-key="83">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.btnLetter {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -7px 4px 0 0;
    color: transparent;
    background-clip: text;
    text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px  #805235;
    background-color: black ;
    font-weight: bold;   
}

#controls {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 300px;
    position: relative; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is chrome is not understanding the `background-clip` in css portion.
So provide it like this

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-moz-background-clip: text;
```

instead of

```
background-clip: text;
```

Comment: great, thanks. I thought background-clip was supported by Chrome without the prefix, => https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip